# What is the maximum number of items I can receive from a Pokestop?

Tags: pokemon-go

While walking around yesterday, I hit a quite a few of Pokestops. A majority of the time, I received anywhere between 2 - 5 items from the Pokestop. After a few hours, I assumed that 5 was the cap. However there was an instance where a received 8 items from the Pokestop.

What is the maximum number of items I can receive from a Pokestop?

Comment: As you've noticed, sometimes you can get a lot. I've received 7 or 8, and I've seen 5 pokéballs at once before. I imagine the number is random with decreasing chances of higher numbers. I haven't seen higher than 8, and (at least on my phone) 8 fills up the side of the screen, so maybe that's the cap.

Answer (score 9):

Per [IGN - PokeStops](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/PokeStops), there does not appear to be an overall maximum. There is a maximum number Pokeballs you will receive, as well as randomly receiving various other items as well.

*(Emphasis my own)*

> Most often, a PokeStop will grant you **three to four** items at a time. Until you're level 5, PokeStops will grant you exclusively PokeBalls and Pokemon Eggs. Once you reach level 5, at times PokeStops will generate **up to six** PokeBalls, and other items such as Revives and Potions to use now that your trainer can access Gyms and battle other Pokemon.

Comment: Six is the most I've seen from one Pokéstop, although these are generally pretty rare.

Comment: I've definitely received 8. I want to say it might have been 9, but not so sure.

Answer (score 5):

Just today I received 9 items for the first time from a pokestop.
I have received 8 items several times.
Some time ago (don't remember the site) I have read that there isn't actually a random in receiving a -x- number of items.
Every 10th pokestop you will receive the bonus of 6 or more items.
Only rule is that it have to be 10 different stops (so without taking a stop for 2nd time before receiving the bonus)
I have used this info alot and its true and helps alot.

Comment: Also has to be within 30 minutes. If it takes you more than 30 minutes to visit the 10 Pokestops, it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

The other day I had just woken up I got 21[image]

Comment: Jesus that covers like half your screen o_O

Answer (score 3):

The number of items you receive from a PokeStop is random. You can receive from 3 to 9 items from a PokeStop, but the most common amount is 3-5. There is also an XP bonus if you receive more than 6 items from a PokeStop. If you get 3-6 items, you receive the regular 50 XP. If you get 7-9 items from a PokeStop, you will get 100 XP.

---

Update: content above the horizontal line is based on information from the last time I played, in late August. With the new app updates, it is possible to get numerous items, up to 15 and more!

Comment: I think you are seeing the bonus items and xp from hitting ten unique stops in a row. The xp isn't for getting extra items.

Answer (score 1):

The number of items you can get from a PokéStop at once (not counting the streak bonus) is 3–9: if you are in 1–6 day streak, double the items, if the seventh day of the streak; assuming that 9–15 items or even greater will drop.